# iterating over the results in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

```
    mysql_select_db($database_QASite, $QASite);
$query_getUpperMenu = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE is_top=1";
$getUpperMenu = mysql_query($query_getUpperMenu, $QASite) or die(mysql_error());


    <?php do { 
 if(isset($row['title'])){
    echo mysql_num_rows($getUpperMenu);//This prints 2
?>

        <li class="NOSEPARATOR"><a href="?topic_id_header=<?php echo $row['topic_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>


      <?php
    }
   } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUpperMenu)); 
   ?>
```

prints one iteration only

I have 2 results in the database.. but the iteration continues only once,,..why is that?

UPDATE:

```
       <ul id="Menu1" class="MM" style="position:absolute; left: 20px; top: -27px;" >
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUpperMenu)) { 

        echo mysql_num_rows($getUpperMenu);//prints 2

    ?>

            <li class="NOSEPARATOR"><a href="?topic_id_header=<?php echo $row['topic_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></li>


      <?php

       } 
       ?>
```

Comment: wow. people actually use `do … while`? Oo

Comment: Use a while{} condition instead of do...while. Do...while checks at the end.

Comment: what does it matter.. i still get one result... i get one iteration only

Comment: @Gordon I use `do-while(FALSE)` to create code blocks I can easily break out of (dangerously close to `goto`, I know) but obviously in the code above it is the worst loop possible. To the OP: In a `do-while` the condition is executed at the end, so your first iteration will be working with no data... Which is why you've ended having to put that `if(isset($row['title'])){` in.

Comment: That is very true, Dave..see the update.. I still get one iteration

Comment: With 2 rows, it's correct that the iteration continues once only: (row1), continue1, (row2). - So what is your question/issue?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd can you update with the HTML that is actually generated by this code?

Comment: I think i fixed it.. it iterates once, if u iterate before the loop ..I put this line before the loop...$row_getUpperMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUpperMenu);.... how can I return to the 0 position in the iteration (not in the loop),,but the database position..before i iterate

Comment: @gordon - do ... while always has a place in coding when you need to guarantee at least one iteration, it's just that most people don't think about end checks rather than begin checks... pascal had repeat/until for the same purpose

Comment: @MarkBaker pascal? may i call you old fashioned ;)

Comment: @gordon - I've been called worse :) ... it was one of the first languages I learned

Answer (score 0):

Try mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc.